# Simple java exam question, accessing methods from other classes

Tags: java

There are given two classes `Person.java` and `Employee.java`, make the necessary changes in the `Person.java` in order that the `displayMessage` method will be executed when the program is running.

**Person.java**

```java
public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

**Employee.java**

```java
public class Employee {    
    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.println("This text is defined in the second class");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Turing85 Please be nice as it is a new contributor. He/she should be given some time/a warm welcome to understand how the site works. @elcr; Simply copy-pasting your homework is often frowned upon here on StackOverflow; you might want to read this ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is *initialize* the Employee class in your main method inside the Person class. After you initialize an employee *object*, you can use that *instance* of the class to call the method inside the Employee class. I am deliberately using Object Oriented Programming terminology here to get you familiar with it.

Here's how to implement it:

```
//Employee remains unchanged
public class Employee {

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.println("This text is defined in the second class");
    }
}


//Here you initialize a new Employee (peter in this case)
public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee peter = new Employee();
        peter.displayMessage();

    }
}
```